# ImageView Visível com onClick ficar invisível novamente?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, onclick, imageview

Fala galera, 
Eu tenho um Imagem que inicia invisível e ao clicar no botão ela fica visível, porém eu preciso que ela fique invisível novamente pois ao clicar no botão novamente, ela tem que tornar a aparecer, devido ter "sumido" por tempo na animação. Tem uma maneira simples de fazer isso? Pois por métodos ou Classes, sempre me enrolo. Pois não acho a explicação completa de como puxar o método e talz.

Edit para Código funcionando.

```
btQuestions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            seuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            seuLayout.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(5000);
            showButtons();


            }
        });
```

Obs: seuLayout tem que estar INVISIBLE no xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um `Handler`, que é uma classe que agenda tarefas conforme sua necessidade através de uma `Thread` de acordo com o tempo escolhido.

```
btQuestions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Marcel, agradeço muito, eu consegui fazer com uns tutoriais e juntando informação de uns 3 lugares diferentes. kkkk. Ai depois vim aqui estava a resposta, brigadão.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia. Pra se alguém um dia precisar, ficou dessa forma.
Obs: o *seuLayout é o Relative, contrain, linear... que fará a ação em tudo que tiver dentro.
O .alpha(1f).setDuration(0); é pra tornar a ver o seuLayout novamente pois no clique do botão além de ficar visível tinha animação pra ir sumindo após um tempo. E pra completar após um tempo seuLayout volta a ficar INVISIBLE, para que a ação do botão possa tornar ele VISIBLE novamente conforme necessidade.

```
private void showButtons(){

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            seuLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            seuLayout.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(0);
    }
},2000); //Tempo para tornar seuLayout INVISIBLE.

}
```

Para puxar o método pra dentro do onClick usei showButtons(); dentro da ação do botão.